# How should I structure 3D data for quick and simple searches

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a list of type A's which are all unique. Each unique Type A has a list of subclass type B's which are also all unique. Each unique Type B has a subclass list of unique type C's. Each unique type C has data that I want to access.

structure = [A1[B1[C1->$, C2->$, ..], B2[C1->$, C2->$, ..] ..], A2[B1[C1->$, C2->$, ..], B2[C1->$, C2->$, ..] ...]

How should I structure this so that by entering structure[A[B[C]]] (with with A, B, and C being the name of that type) I can get the data ($) connected to C?

Comment: How would a 3D list be inefficient? Is the data not equally spaced? Maybe nested dictionaries would be more appropriate? Either way, you have omitted many important details and examples. Your question is very unclear, and therefore likely to be closed. Please include your coded attempt as well as expected output. Perhaps read up on [MCVE's](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [questions to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Reedinationer searching for a C's data would take (O)n^3 time. I was imagining of a tree like structure that might take (O)logn time for searches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just interested in the time complexity, then dictionaries would be ideal. With dictionaries you can use:

```
if key in dict:
```

which is O(n), but you can also be smart about it and use:

```
if dict.get(key):
```

which is O(1). Therefore if you use a dictionary of dictionaries of lists (which sounds like what you are looking for), the only part that depends on `n` is the small sublist of data and your time complexity should be rather small. If you are iterating over every `A` and `B` within a calculation anyways though, then this wouldn't help at all since you need to look at all the elements anyways (your usage is not specified anywhere in your question -> part of why it is so vague). An example of creating data with this suggested structure would look like:

```
import random
import pprint

my_data = {}
for i in range(5):
    a_data = {}
    for j in range(5):
        a_data.update({"B{}".format(j): [random.random() for _ in range(5)]})
    my_data.update({"A{}".format(i): a_data})
pprint.pprint(my_data)
```

Which could probably be condensed further into a dictionary comprehension

The sample output (will vary randomly):

```
{'A0': {'B0': [0.6485522824432963,
               0.11868349154755786,
               0.47993696031349975,
               0.7160266451492747,
               0.20422803457802052],
        'B1': [0.9380849431204785,
               0.6539834754308227,
               0.5611744002365067,
               0.2133551310993106,
               0.8949133730542626],
        'B2': [0.36760450018709423,
               0.9642998035743341,
               0.8586193370301718,
               0.08752038491887604,
               0.024599163698393545],
        'B3': [0.6628339212749838,
               0.8048498500149749,
               0.9907755186375856,
               0.6645723436082659,
               0.5174314787866218],
        'B4': [0.6822316343068052,
               0.9746732114075276,
               0.0020534953463460237,
               0.014356025076888712,
               0.6772670570788119]},
 'A1': {'B0': [0.7378737756652298,
               0.14039653522444384,
               0.47866456134664226,
               0.10738625746147012,
               0.9090969468727612],
        'B1': [0.5704370315691024,
               0.49376710197367923,
               0.8274989999126723,
               0.038214369468485554,
               0.17009580012847048],
        'B2': [0.6939259391972035,
               0.9110338881076743,
               0.7555660985773318,
               0.8481190623903578,
               0.014120291785718053],
        'B3': [0.8499548396499972,
               0.20076400822186358,
               0.14614534339302976,
               0.7739094289912056,
               0.04764385923213177],
        'B4': [0.6912718710522611,
               0.8048111007740021,
               0.44931260952976737,
               0.43128050004601304,
               0.3531236544706029]},
 'A2': {'B0': [0.46528144439859476,
               0.0205816059228785,
               0.6695456096247111,
               0.9988173243509552,
               0.051905229109018514],
        'B1': [0.04803364032590196,
               0.7868149538296291,
               0.8533198118962502,
               0.29146935162650145,
               0.2807743242922375],
        'B2': [0.36961149956060024,
               0.1353899446333634,
               0.7706754890820899,
               0.29308242140950314,
               0.17034473993878685],
        'B3': [0.8354036374070778,
               0.646151506493819,
               0.32389117378303023,
               0.9528267910999805,
               0.6267618375506382],
        'B4': [0.6145598883893689,
               0.8515986400949234,
               0.6169785789899879,
               0.03362111179099414,
               0.9521634858051836]},
 'A3': {'B0': [0.9318274094709155,
               0.43915402305280726,
               0.5606412356801113,
               0.5667267202619789,
               0.062414540102853966],
        'B1': [0.2726691326644528,
               0.8541546806395977,
               0.39230988690958235,
               0.0807340769728665,
               0.7751605484452384],
        'B2': [0.9397624630926291,
               0.9052167655943475,
               0.7268766594130203,
               0.5576480685216525,
               0.07378990948773556],
        'B3': [0.15565431133081475,
               0.8416385878306458,
               0.5316120963188792,
               0.9439575177462843,
               0.18637945576887305],
        'B4': [0.3403489900532247,
               0.8965320523548347,
               0.2042874328716925,
               0.5828873525254279,
               0.6355562694141039]},
 'A4': {'B0': [0.7249643527845289,
               0.06341000284870268,
               0.5387352294199541,
               0.052360662637426225,
               0.32801302810721134],
        'B1': [0.7535355207856345,
               0.4021768889527224,
               0.4538503143135848,
               0.9537514506760036,
               0.9847844584432128],
        'B2': [0.1581364714502792,
               0.7496047534745104,
               0.8047033267636398,
               0.286167263637672,
               0.6929734594776367],
        'B3': [0.8181548198291808,
               0.9249395805906845,
               0.12083331687949195,
               0.2596558964744917,
               0.8351847447381108],
        'B4': [0.8998021303404342,
               0.12734950119308275,
               0.14539257680624873,
               0.26646182377533223,
               0.7865210152018929]}}
```

Furthermore, this yields your desired syntax for accessing items (I think...) of `my_data["A0"]["B0"][:]`